# Using a random number generator pick one of the three animals

Tags: perl, variable-assignment

The task:

> Write a program that creates three different variables, all with names of animals assigned to them (one animal per variable). Display the three animals for the user. Have a random number generator pick one of the three animals, and ask the user to guess which animal was chosen. Let the user know whether they guessed correctly or not.

That part that I don't know is "Have a random number generator pick one of the three animals".

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/user/bin/perl
# File Assignment1.pl

use warnings;

$a1 = "Cat";
$a2 = "Dog";
$a3 = "Lion";

print "You have three animals: $a1, $a2, $a3";

$num = 1 + int(rand(3));    # I'm not sure of this

print "\nChoose which animal has been chosen?\n";
print "Answer: ";
$ans = <STDIN>;
chomp $ans;

if ($ans eq $num) {
    print "\nYour guess is correct!\n";
} else {
    print "Your guess is incorrect\n";
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: your question should explain what's wrong with your code

Comment: How much is `int(rand 'Cat') + 'Lion'`?

Comment: @choroba Is it 'a big cat'?

Comment: wow, what a horrible problem.  why would the instructor want to encourage keeping structured data (a list of animals) in an unstructured form (one variable per animal)

Comment: @ysth Probably to show the advantages of arrays when they are introduced. What takes a complex `if` statement to print the selected animal, all that complex logic is reduced to a single `print`. It would be cool to put all of the animals in a single variable separated by `\0`, and then use `split` to print the actual animal. `print "The animal is: " . (split/\0/, $animals)[$num] ."\n";` That's how we had to implement arrays.

Comment: no complex if statement, just `($one,$two,$three)[rand 3]`

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that `[...]` would work with a non-integers. I still suspect that the teacher is trying to show how arrays (or lists like you have) would make the program so much simpler in order to show what arrays can do.

Comment: `my ($pick) = map $_->[rand @$_], [$one,$two,$three];`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.

```
my $num = int rand 3;
```

will give you 0, 1, or 2, (pseudo-)randomly.

If your values were stored in an array, you could then pick one with `$array[$pick]`. But your assignment is to use scalar variables, not an array. Can you figure out how to use scalars as a list?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I've been trying for half an hour!

Comment: "But your assignment is to use scalar variables, not an array." Nothing in the question says the scalars can't be put in an array.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot A bit of an assumption on my part. The prompt says to create three _different_ variables, and presumably arrays haven't been taught yet (thus creating the three individual variables only to stuff them into an array would go against the spirit of the problem, if not the letter).

Comment: @user3586095: but what did you try?  update your question with something that doesn't pass a string to rand (which expects a numeric parameter).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your use of [rand](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html).

You have:

```
$num = int(rand($a1)) + $a3;
```

`$a1` and `$a3` are not numeric, but strings. Look at the way `rand` works (see the link above). Write a few programs to play around with it and see if you can understand it.

[Slade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471158/368630) gave you an idea how to generate integer values between 0 to 2 inclusive. Once you have that value, you could use an `if/elsif/else` statement to figure out which one to print:

```
if ( $num == 0 ) {
    print "The animal is...";
}
elsif ( $num == 1 ) {
```

Note the double `==` in the comparison! This is for *numeric comparisons*. If you used regular `=`, your `if` would be setting `$num` to zero and not comparing `$num` to zero.

Interestingly, `$num` would then be false since it's zero in value. This causes your program to try the `elsif` statement which would set `$num` to 1, and that would be true.

With `use warnings;`, your program will print out a warning that `=` was found in a conditional.

Arrays would make the whole program a lot easier. Can you use an array variable?

Always `use strict;` along with `use warnings;`. `use strict;` requires you to declare your variables with `my` (like I did above). This prevents errors like this:

```
$name = "Bob";
print "Hello, $naem!\n";
```

I mistyped my `$name` in my `print` as `$naem`. `use strict;` will catch that.

Comment: You're right. It's between 0 to 2 inclusive since it has `int` in front. I'll fix my post.

Comment: Slade has `int rand 3` which will give you 0, 1, or 2.